# approve facebook photos from android app

Tags: android, facebook

My goal is to post pictures from android app to user's facebook wall without asking him to approve it.

I use the following code to publish a picture:

```
String comment = editText.getText().toString();

byte[] data;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", comment);
postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);

Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(SendActivity.this, "Facebook post error.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SendActivity.this, "Posted to facebook!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams,
        HttpMethod.POST, callback);

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

In facebook app settings I added two permissions: user_photos and publish_actions.
The app is not in a sandbox mode.

When I use the app to upload a picture, it goes to an album named same to my app name, and there is a lable that this photos are uploaded from an app, so I need either to approve or to reject it. **How can I post a picture without that "approval" stage?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the publish_stream permission (not publish_action).

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: Is there any prerequisites to add this permisson? Somehow it is not displayed when I  try to add it.

Comment: How are you adding it to your session? Are you calling session.requestNewPublishPermissions?

Comment: Finally I managed to add the permission. But it does not solve my problem.